# Regex expression for |abc-amount

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex for my output

```
|Term Loan-amount or |Bill Purchase / Discounting (Inland)-amount or |PARTNER_NAME-PAN
```

should accept only in this fashion.

Comment: Can you clarify `only in this fashion`? Without specifics any regex might work like "|.+|.+|.+" but very likely not what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to post your attempt and the specific problem you are facing with it to get relevant responses here.

Comment: I want regex which should accept only one from the format i have provided.

Comment: what format have your provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear to us. Still You can try below options if it suits as per your requirement.

Try this one to accept only one

```
String str = "abc |PARTNER_NAME-PAN xyz";

Pattern patter = Pattern
        .compile("(\\|Term Loan-amount|\\|Bill Purchase / Discounting \\(Inland\\)-amount|\\|PARTNER_NAME-PAN)");
Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("accept");
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

---

--EDIT--

or try this one for any `|abc-amount`

```
    String str = "abc |Bill Purchase / Discounting (Inland)-amount xyz";

    Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("(\\|(.*)-amount|\\|PARTNER_NAME-PAN)");
    Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("accept");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

output

```
accept
|Bill Purchase / Discounting (Inland)-amount
```

Comment: Thank you ..... Next time i would be clear with my question sorry.